# PhpStorm 8 - Rename Refactoring - How do I rename a object property throughout my project?

Tags: php, refactoring, phpstorm

In PhpStorm 8, under the 'Refactor' menu the option 'Rename' exists.  If I click on a variable in my code and then select 'Rename', then I believe 'Rename' will attempt to search throughout my project and rename the variable to whatever I wish it to be.  However, if I click on an object property, the 'Rename' option under the 'Refactor' menu remains grayed-out and is apparently not available for renaming object properties.

Thus I am wondering, using Phpstorm 8, what is the quickest method for me to rename an object property throughout my entire project?

Specifically, I am attempting to change a property of my 'country' object from 'name_english' to 'name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your cursor on top of the name of the property definition. Then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (on Mac <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) or right+click and select rename. Make sure your cursor is on the property you want to rename (don't just right+click it).

Comment: Thanks, your answer was the correct answer to my question.  I think the reason I was originally having trouble was because I am using Laravel and I was actually dealing the property of a Laravel model which Phpstorm doesn't seem to like renaming.  At any rate, I have resolved the problem at this point :).